# [Angular 6]How to change field name dynamically from component.ts file

Tags: angular6

I have a template driven angular form whose field names get changed based on the "Country" selected.
I get the field names from a rest endpoint for a selected country and I need to bind the field name accordingly.

I tried to interpolate the field name to a label as in below code but the field name doesnot show up.

[image]

```
<div class="column">
        <label for="example" class="label-text">{{preferences.fieldName}}</label>
        <input type="text" name="example" id="example"
          class="form-control   form-control-sm textfield-size label-text" 
           #example="ngModel"    
          maxlength="{{preferences.fieldLength}}" >  
   </div>
```

I tried to interpolate the value for maxlength , the value is binded properly

Comment: Can you interpolate the whole preferences object and print it here?

Comment: Can you make 'preferences' an observable and use it together with the async pipe?